# Want text to become bold after a checkmark is placed in the box next to it

Tags: jquery, html, css, checkbox

I have a list of things in a web form. Each item on the list has a checkbox next to it. Some of the checkboxes have checkmarks already in them, and others are empty.

I want the text next to the checkbox to turn bold whenever there is a check in the box.

So the text that already has a checkmark in the box next to them by default should appear bold on load.

Item text that has an empty checkbox next to them should turn bold the moment I place a checkmark in it.

How do I do this?

Comment: Some code to show what you had done perhaps?

Comment: So you want us to code for you ?

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to make sure your checkbox comes immediately before the text, and that the text is wrapped in `label` tags:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="will" checked /><label for="will">William</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="sue" /><label for="sue">Susan</label>
```

Then use CSS specific to the checked inputs to make the label after them appear in bold:

```
input:checked+label{font-weight:bold;}
```

[Bingo. http://jsfiddle.net/davmillar/xDtge/](http://jsfiddle.net/davmillar/xDtge/)

Answer (score 0):

Use "onChange" event listener so when you click the checkbox, you can get the "checked" attribute. If it is true, apply a class name on the text to make the text in bold format.

For the automatically appearing bold on load purpose, just use similar code segments as above,  which will run on the load event happens (i.e., in window.onload, or $(document).ready(), etc).

Comment: This is overkill for applying boldness to some text. Useful if doing more than messing with style, but otherwise bad.